# Why my output is blank when I run the script

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to run this code on PL/SOL to show how many activities in sporting clubs are on my database. Here is my code:

```
declare
Sporting_clubs_name sporting_clubs.name%type;
Count_of_activity number(2);
begin
for Sporting_clubs_name in
    (select sporting_clubs.name,
     count(club_activity.activity)
     into Sporting_clubs_name, Count_of_activity
     from sporting_clubs, club_activity
     where sporting_clubs.club_id = club_activity.club_id
     group by sporting_clubs.name)
loop
dbms_output.put_line('The '||Sporting_clubs_name||' has '||Count_of_activity||' activities.');
end loop;
end;
```

When I run it shows:

```
The  has  activities.
The  has  activities.
The  has  activities.
The  has  activities.
```

It should be shown the sporting club's name and count of activity of the output, but the "Sporting_clubs_name" and "Count_of_activity" is blank.

I also change "Sporting_clubs_name" to varchar2(20), but it still not working.

What is wrong is my code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's a while since I've done Oracle, but you're mixing up types. `Sporting_clubs_name sporting_clubs.name%type;` sets `Sporting_clubs_name` to the same type as the `name` field (probably `VARCHAR2`) but then `for Sporting_clubs_name in` uses `Sporting_clubs_name` like a record, not a `VARCHAR2`. I don't have time to research syntax for Oracle cursors, but I suggest you fins an example and understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `select ... into` in a PL/SQL `for .. in (select..)` loop.

`Sporting_clubs_name` is the name of the *loop-varable* and a variable whowse type corresponds to `sporting_clubs.name%type`.

I'd think that the code you posted doesn't even compile.

Remove your variables (`Sporting_clubs_name` and `Count_of_activity`),
give `count(club_activity.activity)` an alias (for example `cnt`) and then use
`dbms_output.put_line('The '||Sporting_clubs_name.name||' has '||Sporting_clubs_name.cnt||' activities.');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

just use implicit cursor loop template like [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_adv_plsql_implicit_cursor_FOR_loop.htm)

```
begin
for c in (select sporting_clubs.name,
     count(club_activity.activity) as cnt    
     from sporting_clubs, club_activity
     where sporting_clubs.club_id = club_activity.club_id
     group by sporting_clubs.name )
loop
  dbms_output.put_line('The '||c.name||' has '||c.cnt||' activities.');

end loop;
end;
```